# How to set <img> max-height: width; without repercussions?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish in pure CSS:

1. I'm given an arbitrary `div`. I know **nothing** about its layout *except* that its height can be sufficiently large to contain the content I will put in it.
   In particular, to be absolutely explicit, this means I don't know its positioning, padding, margins, width, etc. and hence **nothing in the solution should depend on their particular values**.
2. I'm given an image file with arbitrary dimensions to place inside the `div` (directly or indirectly).
3. CSS should scale down the image to ensure its width does not exceed that of its parent.
4. CSS should then crop the image to a circle.

In the end, then, I should see a circular image fit into the div without any aspect distortion, neither of whose dimensions exceed that of the original.

Here's what this would look like in my ideal world:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: width;  /* I wish this was a thing... */
   border-radius: 50%;
   object-fit: cover;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 Arbitrary content...
 <div style="width: 25%; margin-left: 10px; top: 1em;"> <!-- arbitrary -->
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mNMb.png"/>
 </div>
 Arbitrary content...
</body>
</html>
```

Now obviously that doesn't work, because you can't do `height: width`.

But what can I do instead? 
I've tried every trick in the book I could find, but they all end up failing spectacularly in some way or the other. Here's an example with the `height: 0; padding-bottom: 100%;` trick:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .square {
   height: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
  .circle {
   position: absolute;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: 100%;  /* not really sure what to put here */
   border-radius: 0%;
   object-fit: cover;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 Arbitrary content...
 <div style="width: 25%; margin-left: 50px; top: 1em;">
  <div class="square">
   <img class="circle" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mNMb.png"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 Arbitrary content...
</body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: An image with arbitrary dimensions, but are they at least provided? Or is it just whatever the request serves up?

Comment: @Ry-: The latter :\

Comment: What’s behind the image? Solid colour, fixed pattern, arbitrary content?

Comment: @Ry-: A photo, so I guess it falls under arbitrary content...

Comment: You can capitalize on the fact that percentage-based paddings always refer to the `width` of the element, even if applied to `padding-top` and/or `padding-bottom`. So you could work with a `height`: 0;` and `padding: 50% 0;` to get a square `div` at all times.

Comment: @connexo: Isn't that what I tried to do in the second snippet?

Comment: it seems that only `position:relative` is missing in your last snippet so that height is relative to square

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Yeah that's what JasonB mentioned in his answer 15 minutes ago. I'm in the process of testing it out to see if it works on the original project I had, not just this test sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet was close. You need `position:relative;` on the square container so you can set the circle's height and with to 100% of that square container. Using `object-fit: scale-down;` on the img tag seems to do it.

```css
.circle {
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
Arbitrary content...
<div style="width: 25%; margin-left: 50px; top: 1em;">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mNMb.png" />
  </div>
</div>
Arbitrary content...
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/68/50" />
  </div>
</div>
Arbitrary content...
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  </div>
</div>
Arbitrary content...
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" />
  </div>
</div>
Arbitrary content...
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh man... I'm trying this in my actual project and things are completely breaking. I'll try to see if I can fix it I guess, but I didn't expect the tag type to be changed... is there no way to keep the image an `img`? (In all fairness I did ask about `<img>` in the question title...)

Comment: It's not how I would normally do it, so no guarantees, but I have updated the snippet to use an img tag.

Comment: Ahh... this seems to expand the image if it's too small, not just shrink it if it's too large?

Comment: What about `object-fit:scale-down;` - I updated the snippet again

Comment: This one doesn't even work when I click "Run code snippet". And on my project it crops rectangularly after a circular crop.

Comment: I think that you weren't catching the rounded corners in the snippet. I've included examples of your image, an image that is too small, too wide, too tall, and too big. Hope this helps you or someone else figure out what you are going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can capitalize on the fact that percentage-based paddings always refer to the `width` of the parent element, even if applied to `padding-top` and/or `padding-bottom`. So you could work with a `height: 0;` and `padding: 50% 0;` to get a square `div` at all times.

Examples:

```css
div div {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 50% 0;
}

.a {
  width: 20px;
}

.b {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="b">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Now you can simply apply the `background-image` of your choice to `div div`.